# java to MYSQL DateTime Format

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, date

I have an output from an angularjs calendar thats like this: " Date 2015-12-10T02:59:00.000Z"

I need my hava class and mysql field to handle it.
But I seem to be having a lot of trouble making it work...

Im using "private Date asd;" for the java class and timestamp for the mysql.

Java Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "incidente")
public class Incidente implements Serializable {

private Date apertura;

@Column(name = "apertura")
public Date getApertura() {
    return apertura;
}

public void setApertura(Date apertura) {
    this.apertura = apertura;
}
```

Mysql is a simple column with datatype TIMESTAMP

And heres the angularJS output:

```
        (function withAngular(angular, navigator) {
'use strict';

angular.module(
        'incidente',
        [ 'urls', 'ui.bootstrap',
                'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker' ])

.controller('IncidentesController',
        [ '$scope', '$http', 'urlinc', function($scope, $http, urlinc) {

            var url = urlinc.getUrlinc();

            var onIncidenteComplete = function(response) {

                try {
                    $scope.incidentes = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.incidentes);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            };

            $http.get(url).then(onIncidenteComplete);

        } ])

.controller(
        'IncidenteController',
        [
                '$scope',
                '$http',
                '$routeParams',
                'urlinc',
                '$location',
                function($scope, $http, $routeParams, urlinc, $location) {

                    var url = urlinc.getUrlinc();

                    var onError = function(reason) {
                        $scope.error = "No se pudo encontrar";
                    };

                    var code = $routeParams.codename;

                    console.log(code);

                    var onTecnicoComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.tecnicos = response.data;
                    };

                    var onHardwareComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.hardwares = response.data;
                    };

                    var onSoftwareComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.softwares = response.data;
                    };

                    var onSistemaComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.sistemas = response.data;
                    };

                    var onIncidenteComplete = function(response) {

                        try {
                            $scope.incidente = response.data;
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    };

                    $http.get(url + code)
                            .then(onIncidenteComplete, onError);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/tecnico/").then(
                            onTecnicoComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/hardware/").then(
                            onHardwareComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/software/").then(
                            onSoftwareComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/sistema/").then(
                            onSistemaComplete);

                    $scope.saveIncidente = function(incidente) {
                        console.log(incidente);

                        return $http.post(url, incidente).success(
                                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                    var status2 = '/' + status + '/';
                                    $location.url(status2);
                                    return status.data;
                                }).error(function(status) {
                            var status2 = '/' + status.status + '/';
                            console.log(status2);
                            $location.url(status2);
                            return status.data;
                        })
                    };

                    var that = this;

                    this.dates = {
                      apertura: new Date(),
                      cierre: new Date(),
                    };

                    this.open = {
                    apertura: false,
                    cierre: false,
                      };

                    // Disable weekend selection
                    this.disabled = function(date, mode) {
                      return (mode === 'day' && (new Date().toDateString() == date.toDateString()));
                    };

                    this.dateOptions = {
                      showWeeks: false,
                      startingDay: 1
                    };

                    this.timeOptions = {
                      readonlyInput: false,
                      showMeridian: false
                    };

                    this.dateModeOptions = {
                      minMode: 'year',
                      maxMode: 'year'
                    };

                    this.openCalendar = function(e, date) {
                        that.open[date] = true;
                    };


                    $scope.setIndisponibilidad = function(incidente){

                        var cierre = incidente.cierre;

                        var apertura = incidente.apertura;

                        var date1 = Date.parse(cierre);

                        var date2 = Date.parse(apertura);

                        var difference = date1 - date2;
                         console.log(difference);

                        var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60/24);
                        difference -= daysDifference*1000*60*60*24

                        var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
                        difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60

                        var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);
                        difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60

                        var indisponibilidad = daysDifference + ' day/s ' + hoursDifference + ' hour/s ' + minutesDifference + ' minute/s ';

                        console.log(indisponibilidad);

                        this.incidente.indisponibilidad = indisponibilidad;

                    };

                    $scope.hardwares = [];

                    $scope.hardwareListener = function() {
                        console.log($scope.hardwares);
                    }

                    $scope.tecnicoListener = function() {
                        console.log($scope.incidente.tecnico);
                    }

                    $scope.date = new Date();

                    $scope.open = function($event) {
                        $event.preventDefault();
                        $event.stopPropagation();

                        $scope.opened = true;
                    };

                } ])

.controller(
        'CrearIncidenteController',
        [
                '$scope',
                '$http',
                'urlinc',
                '$location',
                function($scope, $http, urlinc, $location) {

                    var url = urlinc.getUrlinc();

                    var onTecnicoComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.tecnicos = response.data;
                    };

                    var onHardwareComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.hardwares = response.data;
                    };

                    var onSoftwareComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.softwares = response.data;
                    };

                    var onSistemaComplete = function(response) {
                        $scope.sistemas = response.data;
                    };

                    $scope.createIncidente = function(incidente) {
                        return $http.post(url, incidente).success(
                                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                    var status2 = '/' + status + '/';
                                    $location.url(status2);
                                    return status.data;
                                }).error(function(status) {
                            var status2 = '/' + status.status + '/';
                            console.log(status2);
                            $location.url(status2);
                            return status.data;
                        })
                    };

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/tecnico/").then(
                            onTecnicoComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/hardware/").then(
                            onHardwareComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/software/").then(
                            onSoftwareComplete);

                    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/sistema/").then(
                            onSistemaComplete);

                } ]);

}(angular, navigator));
```

And heres the datetimepicker Im using:

```
    // https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker
            // Version: 1.2.1
            // Released: 2015-08-26 
            angular
                    .module('ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
                            [ 'ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.position' ])
                    .constant('uiDatetimePickerConfig', {
                        dateFormat : 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm',
                        html5Types : {
                            date : 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                            'datetime-local' : 'dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm',
                            'month' : 'yyyy-MM'
                        },
                        enableDate : true,
                        enableTime : true,
                        todayText : 'Hoy',
                        nowText : 'Ahora',
                        clearText : 'Limpiar',
                        closeText : 'Listo',
                        dateText : 'Fecha',
                        timeText : 'Hora',
                        closeOnDateSelection : true,
                        appendToBody : false,
                        showButtonBar : true
                    })
                    .directive(
                            'datetimePicker',
                            [
                                    '$compile',
                                    '$parse',
                                    '$document',
                                    '$timeout',
                                    '$position',
                                    'dateFilter',
                                    'dateParser',
                                    'uiDatetimePickerConfig',
                                    '$rootScope',
                                    function($compile, $parse, $document, $timeout,
                                            $position, dateFilter, dateParser,
                                            uiDatetimePickerConfig, $rootScope) {
                                        return {
                                            restrict : 'A',
                                            require : 'ngModel',
                                            scope : {
                                                isOpen : '=?',
                                                enableDate : '=?',
                                                enableTime : '=?',
                                                todayText : '@',
                                                nowText : '@',
                                                dateText : '@',
                                                timeText : '@',
                                                clearText : '@',
                                                closeText : '@',
                                                dateDisabled : '&'
                                            },
                                            link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                                                var dateFormat = uiDatetimePickerConfig.dateFormat, closeOnDateSelection = angular
                                                        .isDefined(attrs.closeOnDateSelection) ? scope.$parent
                                                        .$eval(attrs.closeOnDateSelection)
                                                        : uiDatetimePickerConfig.closeOnDateSelection, appendToBody = angular
                                                        .isDefined(attrs.datepickerAppendToBody) ? scope.$parent
                                                        .$eval(attrs.datepickerAppendToBody)
                                                        : uiDatetimePickerConfig.appendToBody;

                                                scope.showButtonBar = angular
                                                        .isDefined(attrs.showButtonBar) ? scope.$parent
                                                        .$eval(attrs.showButtonBar)
                                                        : uiDatetimePickerConfig.showButtonBar;

                                                // determine which pickers should be
                                                // available. Defaults to date and time
                                                scope.enableDate = angular
                                                        .isDefined(scope.enableDate) ? scope.enableDate
                                                        : uiDatetimePickerConfig.enableDate;
                                                scope.enableTime = angular
                                                        .isDefined(scope.enableTime) ? scope.enableTime
                                                        : uiDatetimePickerConfig.enableTime;

                                                // default picker view
                                                scope.showPicker = scope.enableDate ? 'date'
                                                        : 'time';

                                                // get text
                                                scope.getText = function(key) {
                                                    return scope[key + 'Text']
                                                            || uiDatetimePickerConfig[key
                                                                    + 'Text'];
                                                };

                                                var isHtml5DateInput = false;
                                                if (uiDatetimePickerConfig.html5Types[attrs.type]) {
                                                    dateFormat = uiDatetimePickerConfig.html5Types[attrs.type];
                                                    isHtml5DateInput = true;
                                                } else {
                                                    dateFormat = attrs.datepickerPopup
                                                            || uiDatetimePickerConfig.dateFormat;
                                                    attrs
                                                            .$observe(
                                                                    'datetimePicker',
                                                                    function(value) {
                                                                        var newDateFormat = value
                                                                                || uiDatetimePickerConfig.dateFormat;

                                                                        if (newDateFormat !== dateFormat) {
                                                                            dateFormat = newDateFormat;
                                                                            ngModel.$modelValue = null;

                                                                            if (!dateFormat) {
                                                                                throw new Error(
                                                                                        'datetimePicker must have a date format specified.');
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                }

                                                // popup element used to display calendar
                                                var popupEl = angular
                                                        .element(''
                                                                + '<div date-picker-wrap>'
                                                                + '<div datepicker></div>'
                                                                + '</div>'
                                                                + '<div time-picker-wrap>'
                                                                + '<div timepicker style="margin:0 auto"></div>'
                                                                + '</div>');

                                                // get attributes from directive
                                                popupEl.attr({
                                                    'ng-model' : 'date',
                                                    'ng-change' : 'dateSelection(date)'
                                                });

                                                function cameltoDash(string) {
                                                    return string.replace(/([A-Z])/g,
                                                            function($1) {
                                                                return '-'
                                                                        + $1.toLowerCase();
                                                            });
                                                }

                                                // datepicker element
                                                var datepickerEl = angular.element(popupEl
                                                        .children()[0]);

                                                if (isHtml5DateInput) {
                                                    if (attrs.type === 'month') {
                                                        datepickerEl.attr(
                                                                'datepicker-mode',
                                                                '"month"');
                                                        datepickerEl.attr('min-mode',
                                                                'month');
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if (attrs.datepickerOptions) {
                                                    var options = scope.$parent
                                                            .$eval(attrs.datepickerOptions);

                                                    if (options && options.initDate) {
                                                        scope.initDate = options.initDate;
                                                        datepickerEl.attr('init-date',
                                                                'initDate');
                                                        delete options.initDate;
                                                    }

                                                    angular
                                                            .forEach(
                                                                    options,
                                                                    function(value, option) {
                                                                        datepickerEl
                                                                                .attr(
                                                                                        cameltoDash(option),
                                                                                        value);
                                                                    });
                                                }

                                                // timepicker element
                                                var timepickerEl = angular.element(popupEl
                                                        .children()[1]);

                                                if (attrs.timepickerOptions) {
                                                    var options = scope.$parent
                                                            .$eval(attrs.timepickerOptions);

                                                    angular
                                                            .forEach(
                                                                    options,
                                                                    function(value, option) {
                                                                        timepickerEl
                                                                                .attr(
                                                                                        cameltoDash(option),
                                                                                        value);
                                                                    });
                                                }

                                                // set datepickerMode to day by default as
                                                // need to create watch
                                                // else disabled cannot pass in mode
                                                if (!angular
                                                        .isDefined(attrs['datepickerMode'])) {
                                                    attrs['datepickerMode'] = 'day';
                                                }

                                                scope.watchData = {};
                                                angular
                                                        .forEach(
                                                                [ 'minMode', 'maxMode',
                                                                        'minDate',
                                                                        'maxDate',
                                                                        'datepickerMode',
                                                                        'initDate',
                                                                        'shortcutPropagation' ],
                                                                function(key) {
                                                                    if (attrs[key]) {
                                                                        var getAttribute = $parse(attrs[key]);
                                                                        scope.$parent
                                                                                .$watch(
                                                                                        getAttribute,
                                                                                        function(
                                                                                                value) {
                                                                                            scope.watchData[key] = value;
                                                                                        });
                                                                        datepickerEl
                                                                                .attr(
                                                                                        cameltoDash(key),
                                                                                        'watchData.'
                                                                                                + key);

                                                                        // Propagate changes
                                                                        // from datepicker
                                                                        // to outside
                                                                        if (key === 'datepickerMode') {
                                                                            var setAttribute = getAttribute.assign;
                                                                            scope
                                                                                    .$watch(
                                                                                            'watchData.'
                                                                                                    + key,
                                                                                            function(
                                                                                                    value,
                                                                                                    oldvalue) {
                                                                                                if (angular
                                                                                                        .isFunction(setAttribute)
                                                                                                        && value !== oldvalue) {
                                                                                                    setAttribute(
                                                                                                            scope.$parent,
                                                                                                            value);
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            });
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                });

                                                if (attrs.dateDisabled) {
                                                    datepickerEl
                                                            .attr('date-disabled',
                                                                    'dateDisabled({ date: date, mode: mode })');
                                                }

                                                // do not check showWeeks attr, as should be
                                                // used via datePickerOptions

                                                function parseDate(viewValue) {
                                                    if (angular.isNumber(viewValue)) {
                                                        // presumably timestamp to date
                                                        // object
                                                        viewValue = new Date(viewValue);
                                                    }

                                                    if (!viewValue) {
                                                        return null;
                                                    } else if (angular.isDate(viewValue)
                                                            && !isNaN(viewValue)) {
                                                        return viewValue;
                                                    } else if (angular.isString(viewValue)) {
                                                        var date = dateParser.parse(
                                                                viewValue, dateFormat,
                                                                scope.date);
                                                        if (isNaN(date)) {
                                                            return undefined;
                                                        } else {
                                                            return date;
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        return undefined;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                function validator(modelValue, viewValue) {
                                                    var value = modelValue || viewValue;

                                                    if (!attrs.ngRequired && !value) {
                                                        return true;
                                                    }

                                                    if (angular.isNumber(value)) {
                                                        value = new Date(value);
                                                    }
                                                    if (!value) {
                                                        return true;
                                                    } else if (angular.isDate(value)
                                                            && !isNaN(value)) {
                                                        return true;
                                                    } else if (angular.isString(value)) {
                                                        var date = dateParser.parse(value,
                                                                dateFormat);
                                                        return !isNaN(date);
                                                    } else {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if (!isHtml5DateInput) {
                                                    // Internal API to maintain the correct
                                                    // ng-invalid-[key] class
                                                    ngModel.$$parserName = 'datetime';
                                                    ngModel.$validators.datetime = validator;
                                                    ngModel.$parsers.unshift(parseDate);
                                                    ngModel.$formatters
                                                            .push(function(value) {
                                                                scope.date = value;
                                                                return ngModel
                                                                        .$isEmpty(value) ? value
                                                                        : dateFilter(value,
                                                                                dateFormat);
                                                            });
                                                } else {
                                                    ngModel.$formatters
                                                            .push(function(value) {
                                                                scope.date = value;
                                                                return value;
                                                            });
                                                }

                                                // Inner change
                                                scope.dateSelection = function(dt) {

                                                    // check which picker is being shown, if
                                                    // its date, all is fine and this is the
                                                    // date
                                                    // we will use, if its the timePicker
                                                    // and enableDate = true, we need to
                                                    // merge
                                                    // the values, else timePicker will
                                                    // reset the date
                                                    if (scope.enableDate
                                                            && scope.enableTime
                                                            && scope.showPicker === 'time') {
                                                        if (scope.date
                                                                && scope.date !== null
                                                                || dt || dt != null) {
                                                            // dt will not be undefined if
                                                            // the now or today button is
                                                            // pressed
                                                            if (dt && dt != null) {
                                                                // get the existing date and
                                                                // update the time
                                                                var date = new Date(
                                                                        scope.date);
                                                                date
                                                                        .setHours(dt
                                                                                .getHours());
                                                                date.setMinutes(dt
                                                                        .getMinutes());
                                                                dt = date;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    if (angular.isDefined(dt)) {
                                                        scope.date = dt;
                                                    }

                                                    var date = scope.date ? dateFilter(
                                                            scope.date, dateFormat) : null;

                                                    element.val(date);
                                                    ngModel.$setViewValue(date);

                                                    if (dt === null) {
                                                        scope.close();
                                                    } else if (closeOnDateSelection) {
                                                        // do not close when using
                                                        // timePicker as make impossible to
                                                        // choose a time
                                                        if (scope.showPicker != 'time') {
                                                            // if time is enabled, swap to
                                                            // timePicker
                                                            if (scope.enableTime) {
                                                                // need to delay this, else
                                                                // timePicker never shown
                                                                $timeout(
                                                                        function() {
                                                                            scope.showPicker = 'time';
                                                                        }, 0);
                                                            } else {
                                                                scope.close();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                };

                                                // Detect changes in the view from the text
                                                // box
                                                ngModel.$viewChangeListeners
                                                        .push(function() {
                                                            scope.date = dateParser.parse(
                                                                    ngModel.$viewValue,
                                                                    dateFormat, scope.date);
                                                        });

                                                var documentClickBind = function(event) {
                                                    if (scope.isOpen
                                                            && event.target !== element[0]) {
                                                        scope.$apply(function() {
                                                            scope.close();
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                };

                                                var inputKeydownBind = function(evt) {
                                                    if (evt.which === 27 && scope.isOpen) {
                                                        evt.preventDefault();
                                                        evt.stopPropagation();
                                                        scope.$apply(function() {
                                                            scope.close();
                                                        });
                                                        element[0].focus();
                                                    } else if (evt.which === 40
                                                            && !scope.isOpen) {
                                                        evt.preventDefault();
                                                        evt.stopPropagation();
                                                        scope.$apply(function() {
                                                            scope.isOpen = true;
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                };
                                                element.bind('keydown', inputKeydownBind);

                                                scope.keydown = function(evt) {
                                                    if (evt.which === 27) {
                                                        scope.close();
                                                        element[0].focus();
                                                    }
                                                };

                                                scope
                                                        .$watch(
                                                                'isOpen',
                                                                function(value) {
                                                                    scope.dropdownStyle = {
                                                                        display : value ? 'block'
                                                                                : 'none'
                                                                    };

                                                                    if (value) {
                                                                        var position = appendToBody ? $position
                                                                                .offset(element)
                                                                                : $position
                                                                                        .position(element);

                                                                        if (appendToBody) {
                                                                            scope.dropdownStyle.top = (position.top + element
                                                                                    .prop('offsetHeight'))
                                                                                    + 'px';
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            scope.dropdownStyle.top = undefined;
                                                                        }

                                                                        scope.dropdownStyle.left = position.left
                                                                                + 'px';

                                                                        $timeout(
                                                                                function() {
                                                                                    scope
                                                                                            .$broadcast('datepicker.focus');
                                                                                    $document
                                                                                            .bind(
                                                                                                    'click',
                                                                                                    documentClickBind);
                                                                                }, 0, false);
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        $document
                                                                                .unbind(
                                                                                        'click',
                                                                                        documentClickBind);
                                                                    }
                                                                });

                                                scope.isDisabled = function(date) {
                                                    var isToday = (date == 'today');

                                                    if (date === 'today' || date === 'now')
                                                        date = new Date();

                                                    if (attrs.dateDisabled) {
                                                        return scope
                                                                .dateDisabled({
                                                                    date : date,
                                                                    mode : scope.watchData['datepickerMode']
                                                                });
                                                    } else {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                };

                                                scope.select = function(date) {

                                                    var isNow = date === 'now';

                                                    if (date === 'today' || date == 'now') {
                                                        var now = new Date();
                                                        if (angular.isDate(scope.date)) {
                                                            date = new Date(scope.date);
                                                            date.setFullYear(now
                                                                    .getFullYear(), now
                                                                    .getMonth(), now
                                                                    .getDate());
                                                            date.setHours(now.getHours(),
                                                                    now.getMinutes());
                                                        } else {
                                                            date = now;
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    scope.dateSelection(date);
                                                };

                                                scope.close = function() {
                                                    scope.isOpen = false;

                                                    // if enableDate and enableTime are
                                                    // true, reopen the picker in date mode
                                                    // first
                                                    if (scope.enableDate
                                                            && scope.enableTime)
                                                        scope.showPicker = 'date';

                                                    element[0].focus();
                                                };

                                                scope.changePicker = function(evt, picker) {
                                                    evt.preventDefault();
                                                    evt.stopPropagation();

                                                    scope.showPicker = picker;
                                                };

                                                var $popup = $compile(popupEl)(scope);
                                                // Prevent jQuery cache memory leak
                                                // (template is now redundant after linking)
                                                popupEl.remove();

                                                if (appendToBody) {
                                                    $document.find('body').append($popup);
                                                } else {
                                                    element.after($popup);
                                                }

                                                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                                                    if (scope.isOpen === true) {
                                                        if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                                                            scope.$apply(function() {
                                                                scope.close();
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    $popup.remove();
                                                    element.unbind('keydown',
                                                            inputKeydownBind);
                                                    $document.unbind('click',
                                                            documentClickBind);
                                                });
                                            }
                                        };
                                    } ])

                    .directive('datePickerWrap', function() {
                        return {
                            restrict : 'EA',
                            replace : true,
                            transclude : true,
                            templateUrl : 'template/date-picker.html'
                        };
                    })

                    .directive('timePickerWrap', function() {
                        return {
                            restrict : 'EA',
                            replace : true,
                            transclude : true,
                            templateUrl : 'template/time-picker.html'
                        };
                    });

            angular
                    .module('ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker')
                    .run(
                            [
                                    '$templateCache',
                                    function($templateCache) {
                                        'use strict';

                                        $templateCache
                                                .put(
                                                        'template/date-picker.html',
                                                        "<ul ng-if=\"isOpen && showPicker == 'date'\" class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left datetime-picker-dropdown\" ng-style=dropdownStyle style=left:inherit ng-keydown=keydown($event) ng-click=$event.stopPropagation()><li style=\"padding:0 5px 5px 5px\" class=date-picker-menu><div ng-transclude></div></li><li ng-if=showButtonBar style=padding:5px><span class=\"btn-group pull-left\" style=margin-right:10px><button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"select('today')\" ng-disabled=\"isDisabled('today')\">{{ getText('today') }}</button> <button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\" ng-click=select(null)>{{ getText('clear') }}</button></span> <span class=\"btn-group pull-right\"><button ng-if=enableTime type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" ng-click=\"changePicker($event, 'time')\">{{ getText('time')}}</button> <button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\" ng-click=close()>{{ getText('close') }}</button></span></li></ul>");

                                        $templateCache
                                                .put(
                                                        'template/time-picker.html',
                                                        "<ul ng-if=\"isOpen && showPicker == 'time'\" class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left datetime-picker-dropdown\" ng-style=dropdownStyle style=left:inherit ng-keydown=keydown($event) ng-click=$event.stopPropagation()><li style=\"padding:0 5px 5px 5px\" class=time-picker-menu><div ng-transclude></div></li><li ng-if=showButtonBar style=padding:5px><span class=\"btn-group pull-left\" style=margin-right:10px><button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"select('now')\" ng-disabled=\"isDisabled('now')\">{{ getText('now') }}</button> <button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\" ng-click=select(null)>{{ getText('clear') }}</button></span> <span class=\"btn-group pull-right\"><button ng-if=enableDate type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" ng-click=\"changePicker($event, 'date')\">{{ getText('date')}}</button> <button type=button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\" ng-click=close()>{{ getText('close') }}</button></span></li></ul>");

                                    } ]);
```

[image: Heres how it shows in the datepicker]

Comment: Where's the code though?

Comment: Added the code for clarity

Comment: "I seem to be having a lot of trouble making it work...". What is the exact issue? Where does the application not demonstrate the expected behaviour? Writing to the database? Displaying in the UI? How is the data marshalled from JSON to Java etc.

Comment: The data keeps showing up as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" in the UI, I'll add a pic in the main post, and It should show up formated like in the date picker .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date date = format.parse("2015-12-10T02:59:00.000Z");
System.out.println(date);
```

Prints this in my system (European time zone):

> Thu Dec 10 03:59:00 CET 2015